# How to enable logging in org.slf4j for the version: '2.0.0-alpha1' in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, maven-plugin

I have used SLF4J logging to print all the logs. I am using the latest version of org.slf4j.

> implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.0-alpha1'
>
> implementation 'org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:2.0.0-alpha1'

But I'm getting the following error and also no logs are being printed.

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
SLF4J: Class path contains SLF4J bindings targeting slf4j-api versions prior to 1.8.
SLF4J: Ignoring binding found at [jar:file:/home/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/7c4f3c474fb2c041d8028740440937705ebb473a/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#ignoredBindings for an explanation.
```

The logs are working fine with the older version (1.7.25). Is there anything needs to be added or configured on the project so that these logs can be printed

Comment: Could you share your POM file here? It will help in understanding what dependencies are being used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will print the messages adding slf4j-log4j12 instead of slf4j-api

Remove the following

```
implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:2.0.0-alpha1'
```

Add

```
implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version: '+'
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to import any log dependency when using **Spring Boot 2.x**. All that is required is to import some [Spring Boot Starter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-starter), which you most likely have already done. E.g. `spring-boot-starter-web`, which depends on `spring-boot-starter-logging`, which pulls in `spring-jcl` module required for logging with Spring Framework.

When using starters, **Logback** is used for logging by default, Log4j is not required.

Just remove all references to `slf4j` from your build file. Here is how the reference to *Spring Boot Web Starter* looks like in the build.gradle file.

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because slf4j is an abstraction that needs binding with other pre-existing libraries. Hence, if you're using simply slf4j to print logs, it wouldn't work because it wouldn't have the settings on logging levels etc. 
[This link](https://dzone.com/articles/logging-with-slf4j) gives some information on the same.

Also, Spring Boot's new version has a default integration with slf4j for version 1.7.9